# Gradle plugin for SonarQube broken with Gradle 3.5-rc-1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I just wanted to upgrade from Gradle 3.4.1 to 3.5-rc-1 and got the following stacktrace. Any hint is appreciated.

```
C:\IdeaProjects\kunde>gradle wrapper --stacktrace
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org/gradle/listener/ActionBroadcast

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/listener/ActionBroadcast
at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin.addBroadcaster(SonarQubePlugin.java:95)
at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin.apply(SonarQubePlugin.java:86)
at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin.apply(SonarQubePlugin.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:140)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:113)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$5.run(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:172)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:210)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:169)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:648)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:126)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:36)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:207)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:146)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:95)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
```

Comment: Have you reported the issue to Gradle developers?

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam No, I didn't report it. Do you consider this issue as a Gradle issue?

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1667

Answer (score 2):

Gradle 3.5-rc-2 is available and https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1667 is solved.